# Determining the order of the tests in DUnitX?

Tags: delphi, dunitx

Execution order of RegisterTestFixture does not work.
DUnitX executing test cases randomly.
How do I determine execution order of the tests in DUnitX?

Comment: If you worry about the order of unit test execution you are doing something wrong - they should be independent of each other and of their order

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stefan. I've customer, product and order domains. In addition I have test units for every domain. Firstly I want to execute product unit test and then customer units test. This tests prepares necessary informations on database for order unit test.This is why I need to order them.

Comment: Don't do that, if tests depend on each other you're essentially doing integration testing, not unit testing. Your product tests should setup a test customer db object in the setup fase...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment you are doing some sort of integration testing which is totally fine to do with DUnitX.

However also integration tests should be self contained and not depend on other tests or their order. For tests on a database you usually have code in setup to prepare the data you want to run tests with and teardown to revert the database to a known state (if the database supports transactions that is usually a way to use them).

The setup and teardown code or parts of them can reused across several tests that do different tests on the same data.

Comment: As you said I think setup and teardown methods are good place for preparing database for tests with transaction. Thanks for clear explanation.