DUNITX sequence of test execution
can I define the sequence my tests are executed  ?
[TestFixture]
  TestTTest = class(TObject)
  strict private

   public
    /// <summary>
    /// called before executiong a test case
    /// </summary>

    procedure SetUp;
    /// <summary>
    /// called after executiong a test case
    /// </summary>

    procedure TearDown;


    [Test]
    procedure TestCreate;

    [Test]
    procedure TestA;

    [Test]
    procedure TestB;

    [Test]
    procedure TestObjectsDelete;
    end;

in the given example I want  the sequence  executed  as defined  in the  code , but I figured out  the sequence  is more or less random while executing my scripts . Can not move this  to setup and teardown  function .

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/61759079/2292722 Duplicate?

If a test relies on the outcome of another test, then you are not testing correctly

the input of test B is a correctly  tested output  of stage A  ,  how to solve  it the other way round?

As already suggested, tests should be independent of each other. The order that they run should make no difference. If the order of execution matters, then you aren't testing in isolation.
The correct way to do what you want is to move your two tests to different classes and set the initial conditions for your tests in the setup method instead of relying on another test to do it.
If you wanted to take a (not recommended) shortcut, you could combine the code from both of these tests into a single test with multiple asserts. You'd be losing some of the benefits of unit testing, but it might be a quick and dirty way to get started.
